# Show loading animation in parent component depending on async values from child components

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a parent component with two or more child components that both asynchronously fetch data from an API. I want to show a loading animation in the parent component until both child components are finished fetching the data. I had the idea to create a property `loading: number` on a shared service and increment/decrement the value from the child components. The parent component would have a `*ngIf="loading === 0"` to conditionally show the loading animation. However, as some might already suspect, this leads to changedAfterChecked error since I am updating the parent view from a child component.

I have already managed to get it working by manually updating the view but this is not an elegant solution. Hence, I wanted to ask if there is any other way or pattern to achieve the beforementioned.

Comment: The most elegant way would be the use of ngrx probably as you can listen to store changes with observables and change accordingly. Otherwise having a `Subject` (from rxjs) with different flag is also another way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Output` to notify parent it child's current state. This will correctly trigger change detection withing angular component lifecycle. For example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.css'],
})
export class ChildComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output()
  state = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let s = true;
    setInterval(() => {
      this.state.next(s);
      s = !s;
    }, 500);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  childStatus=false;
}
```

And parent template:

```
   Child state: {{ childStatus }}
  <app-child-component (state)="childStatus = $event"> </app-child-component>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hfhqap?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use combinelatest in the parent and @output in the children to emit data to, the parent from children.

Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value.

**In your childreen component**

```
@Output() someEvent = this.someSource$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  debounceTime(this.fetchMyData)
);
```

**In your parent**

```
// html file
...
<child (someEvent)="event1$"></child>
<child (someEvent)="event2$"></child>
...

// TS file

// Hide or show loader
loader = false;
...
combineLatest(event1$, event2$).subscribe(
  ([eventOne, eventTwo]) => {
    if(!!eventOne && !!eventTwo) {
      this.loader = false;
    }
  }
);
```

combinelatest : https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest